# Background music for Kids, looking for suggestions on instruments and ornaments

Tags: instruments, ornaments

[This piece of music](https://soundcloud.com/rraallvv/theme-1) is intended to be played seamlessly in an endless loop. The piece has easy to follow and memorable melodies with a bit of irreverence at the beginning and at the end but with a sedated pace in the middle.

Now I wanted to add some ornaments and/or maybe change the instruments to give it just a bit more of an irreverent mood. Any suggestion on how can it be accomplished?

Tuba
[image]

Strings
[image]

Flute
[image]

Comment: This may seem like a joke, but I'm serious: check out Terry Riley's [In C](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjGsO3js6fUAhWpyoMKHSt8D8kQyCkIKjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DyNi0bukYRnA&usg=AFQjCNH9R8vdJUjrglQA4tFH3FFcavRPAA&sig2=UJ99V15j-5wKI09Fo4edFg).

Comment: What a fun project! For the tuba part, slurs and dynamics (crescendos and decrescendos) might work better than ornaments. Specifically, the last note of bar 2 could slur and swell (like a slip and slide) into the first note of bar 3, followed by a quick decrescendo that would, believe it or not, emphasize the relatively high note (for a tuba) that follows by de-emphasizing it. If your audience isn't giggling by then, this question will be  closed for being opinion based.

Comment: Ps. Many performers will interpret what you have already written in delightfully irreverent or playful and sensitive ways if you just tell them where, when (and, perhaps, why; you will learn from their ideas of how). You can even write in "irreverent," "bouncy," "saucy," "calm" - whatever - in the language of your choice if you don't want to get Italian.

Comment: @musicn thanks for your suggestions, I'll be glad to accept those as an answer.

Comment: I'm very glad that you see something in that, rraallvv! It just seemed too partial to post. (I have much to say about tuba parts and performers in general, but much less about strings and woodwinds in particular.)

Comment: @musicn the question seems too broad indeed, nevertheless your comments have pointed me in the right direction, thanks.

Comment: The comment about avoiding tuba ornaments doesn't necessarily  apply to higher parts. (But if it leads to other ideas, all the better!) It's just that ornaments in the lowest ranges wind up sounding like other effects that can be accomplished in simpler terms. (For completeness, yes, a tuba turn around middle C is the most beautiful ornament of all.)

Comment: @musicn I liked the slurs so much that ended up adding three in total (last note in all bars except for the 4th bar), those gave the piece all the irreverence it needed.